# Error parsing the SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-delete

What is the problem with this query:

```
 string DelteQuerry = "DELETE ID,radif,Name, Type, Description, Price, city FROM Users WHERE ID = '" + searchtxt.Text + "'";
```

it will show parsing error:

> [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = ( ]

Please help

Comment: Try `DELETE FROM ...`

Comment: In addition, make sure you are certain that `searchtxt.Text` cannot contain a single quote, or always comes from a trusted source (so not a user of your webapp).

Comment: i use same query in INSERT and that is worked

Comment: the error is 

There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 10,Token in error = , ]

Comment: print `DelteQuerry` and see what output it generate.

Comment: Unlike `INSERT` queries, `DELETE` queries do not expect or allow any column names.  They would be redundant, because you can delete only whole rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string DelteQuerry = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE ID = '" + searchtxt.Text + "'";
```

Comment: no not worked by the way Delete what

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_(SQL)

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: the error is There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 10,Token in error = , ]

Comment: But there is no character "," (comma) at position 10 in my suggested query?! I would expect a different message now.